# Why does not bash short-circuit work in this case?

Tags: bash, short-circuiting

Suppose I am writing the following in a `bash` script:

```
if [ -z $a ] || [ -z $b ] ; then
    usage
fi
```

It works but I would like to write it with `short-circuiting` as follows:

```
[ -z $a ] || [ -z $b ] || usage
```

Unfortunately it does not work. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want to execute `usage` in case either 1st or 2nd condition are accomplished. For that, you can do:

```
[ -z $a ] || [ -z $b ] && usage
```

#### Test:

```
$ [ -z "$a" ] || [ -z "$b" ] && echo "yes"
yes
$ b="a"
$ [ -z "$a" ] || [ -z "$b" ] && echo "yes"
yes
$ a="a"
$ [ -z "$a" ] || [ -z "$b" ] && echo "yes"
$
```

Comment: I just learned here that `||` and `&&` have equal precedence in bash (different from C, Java, etc.).

Answer (score 8):

You could make use of the [following form](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs):

```
[[ expression ]]
```

and say:

```
[[ -z "$a" || -z "$b" ]] && usage
```

This would execute `usage` if either `a` or `b` is empty.

---

Always quote your variables.  Saying

```
[ -z $a ]
```

if the variable `a` is set to `foo bar` would return an error:

```
bash: [: foo: binary operator expected
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out the superior (bash-only) `[[...]]` construct; while it's good practice to always quote, strictly speaking you do _not_ need to quote variable references inside `[[...]]` (while, by contrast, you do have to quote inside `[...]`).

Comment: @mklement0 While it might not be necessary to quote within `[[ ]]`, it's probably worth quoting for the sake of practice.  Omitting it when needed causes much sorrow.